# Display another html Page in Iframe on Parent Html Page

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have one base html page and i have a div, clicking on which should show another html page on that same base html page, in an iframe which i have inserted and kept as display:none.

Please help out !!!

[the screenshots shows the div on which i am clicking and whole page should get replaced by another html page in an iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQLAt.png)

Below is the iframe and html on base html page with a js function which i was trying to implement to achieve this...

```
        <iframe id='ifr'></iframe>
        <span id="previousemployment" onclick="previousemploymentIframe()">Previous Employment</span>
```

JS is

```
      function previousemploymentIframe() 
      {
         document.getElementById("ifr").src ='PreviousEmployment.html';
      }
```

Comment: i am having trouble inserting that @RobertScoloni

Comment: make sure there are two spaces after your last line of text, then press space bar 4 times before you start writing your code

Comment: Got it i just went through the instructions. Thanks @RobertScoloni

Comment: Is the file you are referencing a valid file, and is that a valid path?

Comment: @WookieCoder Yes its in the same folder where my base html file is situated at but still in consol (firebug ) it says 404 not found.. Please help out.

Comment: I have also tried giving the exact path as well but still the html page is not getting found...

Comment: @Simple did you think about users who have their JS disabled? If the iframe contains a page crucial to your website, I'd rather use another approach because your site will appear broken to users with disabled javascirpt.

Comment: @PowerUser i never thought about it but you have got a very valid point here. I am getting second thoughts now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look a t this snippet and apply the code to your own page. From what I gather, you are using the text of the span as a link/button?

```js
function prevEmpIframe() {
  var ifr = document.getElementById("ifr");
  ifr.src = 'PreviousEmployment.html';
}

//Crossbrowser Access of Iframe from Parent Page

var doc = iframe.contentDocument ? iframe.contentDocument : 
(iframe.contentWindow ? iframe.contentWindow.document : iframe.document);
```

```css
#prevEmp.show {
  display: block;
}
#prevEmp.hide {
  display: none;
}
#prevEmp { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <base href="/" target="_self">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <section>
    <span id="prevEmp" onclick="prevEmpIframe()">Previous Employment
          <iframe id='ifr' src="/"></iframe>
      </span>
  </section>
  <script>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it works but i am going with href at the moment and will work on these advanced things later.

Comment: The `href` on `<base>`? Yeah, it's helpful in your situation. On your child `PreviousEmployment.html` change `<base href="{{{SharedPath}}}/" target="_parent">` or `_top`